# How do I increase the number of samples plotted?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

Firstly, I'm not entirely sure whether what I'm doing is correct hahha.
This could also be a problem of my understanding of the concepts.

These are the instructions in our lab activity:

1.Create a sinusoid (sin 2*pi*50*t) with an amplitude of (SeatNo *0.1) with a sampling frequency of:

a. 8000 Hz and plot the graph to show up to 200 samples.

c.  4050 Hz and plot the graph to show up to 200 samples.

This is my attempt at that:

```
amp = 12*0.1; %amplitude
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Number 1     %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%sinusoidal wave
figure(1);
n = 200; %samples

%plot a
subplot(2,2,1);
fs = 8000; %sampling frequency
a = num1(fs, amp, n);
plot(a);
title('Plot 1a');

%plot c
subplot(2,2,3);
fs = 4050; %sampling frequency
c = num1(fs, amp, n);
plot(c);
title('Plot 1c');

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Number 1     %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
function y = num1(fs, amp, n)
%solves for the sinusoidal signal using the given
    t = (1/fs)*n;
    t = linspace(0, numSec, n);
    y = amp*sin(2*pi*50*t);
end
```

Now here's what I don't understand how to do:

2.Compare the length of signals in 1a and 1c. If required, perform zero-padding at the end of the shorter signal so that they will have the same length and

a.  Add the two signals and plot 250 samples.

I already have sigadd function, and have added the signals but it's 200 samples. How do I make it plot 250 samples?

Comment: The 2 signals need to be the same length in time, not in number of points. The addition should be time-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part about comparing the length of signals in 1a and 1c does not make sense to me.  They can be whatever length you want.  In my sample code, I made each signal 1000 points long so that there would always be plenty of points available for plotting.  If you want to get the length of a vector, you could use the length function.

To add the two signals, they should be the same sample rate, so in my sample code, I used interp1 to downsample the higher sample rate signal to the same sample rate as the lower signal.

To control how many points are plotted, I make a variable called k that is used to control which points are plotted.

Here is the code to do what is asked:

```
amp = 12*0.1; %amplitude

%create a
fs_a = 8000; %sampling frequency
t_a = (0:999) / fs_a;
a = amp*sin(2*pi*50*t_a);

%create c
fs_c = 4050; %sampling frequency
t_c = (0:999) / fs_c;
c = amp*sin(2*pi*50*t_c);

% plot a and c
k = 1:200;
figure(1)
plot(t_a(k), a(k), '+-', t_c(k), c(k), 'o-');
xlabel('Time (s)')
grid on
legend('1a', '1c')

% Add a and c
% resample a a the sample rate for c (4050 Hz)
a_resampled = interp1(t_a, a, t_c);
length_a_plus_c = min([length(c), length(a_resampled)]);
a_plus_c = a_resampled(1:length_a_plus_c) + c(1:length_a_plus_c);

% plot a + c
figure(2)
k = 1:250;
plot(t_c(k), a_plus_c(k), 'o-')
grid on
xlabel('Time (s)')
title('a + c')
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me another way to solve the problem! (The part where you solve using a higher than required samples then just plot the required)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this assignment is created to distinguish the difference between summing up signals with respect to time or sample index. Here are some graphs that I came up that use similar resampling techniques to achieve the 250 sample length required for the cumulative signal.

### Summation with Respect to Sample Index:

[image: Respect to Sample Index]

```
clf;
%Configuring Signal 1%
Sampling_Frequency = 8000;
Number_Of_Samples = 200;
Amplitude = 12*0.1;

Sampling_Period = 1/Sampling_Frequency;
t = (0:Sampling_Period:Sampling_Period*(Number_Of_Samples-1));
Signal_1 = Amplitude.*sin(2*pi*50*t);
subplot(3,1,1); plot(t,Signal_1,'Marker','.');
title("Signal 1: 50Hz Sinusoid Samples at " + num2str(Sampling_Frequency) + "Hz");
xlabel("Time (s)"); ylabel("Amplitude");
xlim([0 0.05]);

%Configuring Signal 2%
Sampling_Frequency = 4050;
Number_Of_Samples = 200;
Amplitude = 12*0.1;

Sampling_Period = 1/Sampling_Frequency;
t = (0:Sampling_Period:Sampling_Period*(Number_Of_Samples-1));
Signal_2 = Amplitude.*sin(2*pi*50*t);
subplot(3,1,2); plot(t,Signal_2,'Marker','.');
title("Signal 2: 50Hz Sinusoid Samples at " + num2str(Sampling_Frequency) + "Hz");
xlabel("Time (s)"); ylabel("Amplitude");
xlim([0 0.05]);

%Adding signals with respect to samples%
Cumulative_Signal = Signal_1 + Signal_2;
Samples_Vector = (0:199); Interpolated_Samples_Vector = linspace(0,199,250);
Cumulative_Signal = interp1(Samples_Vector,Cumulative_Signal,Interpolated_Samples_Vector);
subplot(3,1,3); plot(Cumulative_Signal,'Marker','.');
title("Summed with Respect to Samples: Cumulative Signal (Signal 1 + Signal 2)");
xlabel("Sample [n]"); ylabel("Amplitude");
xlim([0 250]);
```

---

### Summation with Respect to Time:

[image: Respect to Time]

```
clf;
%Configuring Signal 1%
Sampling_Frequency = 8000;
Number_Of_Samples = 200;
Amplitude = 12*0.1;

Sampling_Period = 1/Sampling_Frequency;
t = (0:Sampling_Period:Sampling_Period*(Number_Of_Samples-1));
Signal_1 = Amplitude.*sin(2*pi*50*t);
subplot(3,1,1); plot(t,Signal_1,'Marker','.');
title("Signal 1: 50Hz Sinusoid Samples at " + num2str(Sampling_Frequency) + "Hz");
xlabel("Time (s)"); ylabel("Amplitude");
xlim([0 0.05]);

%Configuring Signal 2%
Sampling_Frequency = 4050;
Number_Of_Samples = 200;
Amplitude = 12*0.1;

Sampling_Period = 1/Sampling_Frequency;
t = (0:Sampling_Period:Sampling_Period*(Number_Of_Samples-1));
Signal_2 = Amplitude.*sin(2*pi*50*t);
subplot(3,1,2); plot(t,Signal_2,'Marker','.');
title("Signal 2: 50Hz Sinusoid Samples at " + num2str(Sampling_Frequency) + "Hz");
xlabel("Time (s)"); ylabel("Amplitude");
xlim([0 0.05]);

%Adding signals with respect to time%
Signal_1 = [Signal_1 zeros(1,200)];
Signal_1 = Signal_1(1:2:end);
Samples_Vector = (0:199); Interpolated_Samples_Vector = linspace(0,199,250);
Signal_1 = interp1(Samples_Vector,Signal_1,Interpolated_Samples_Vector);
Signal_2 = interp1(Samples_Vector,Signal_2,Interpolated_Samples_Vector);
End_Time = Sampling_Period*(Number_Of_Samples-1);
t = linspace(0,End_Time,250);
Cumulative_Signal = Signal_1 + Signal_2;
subplot(3,1,3); plot(t,Cumulative_Signal,'Marker','.');
title("Summed with Respect to Time: Cumulative Signal (Signal 1 + Signal 2)");
xlabel("Time (s)"); ylabel("Amplitude");
xlim([0 0.05]);
```

---

### Summation with Respect to Time But Varying Amount of Start Samples:

[image: Adjusted with Respect to Time]

```
clf;
%Configuring Signal 1%
Sampling_Frequency = 8000;
Number_Of_Samples = 200;
Amplitude = 12*0.1;

Sampling_Period = 1/Sampling_Frequency;
t = (0:Sampling_Period:Sampling_Period*(Number_Of_Samples-1));
Signal_1 = Amplitude.*sin(2*pi*50*t);
subplot(3,1,1); plot(t,Signal_1,'Marker','.');
title("Signal 1: 50Hz Sinusoid Samples at " + num2str(Sampling_Frequency) + "Hz (" + num2str(Number_Of_Samples) + " samples)");
xlabel("Time (s)"); ylabel("Amplitude");
xlim([0 0.05]);

%Configuring Signal 2%
Sampling_Frequency = 4050;
Number_Of_Samples = 100;
Amplitude = 12*0.1;

Sampling_Period = 1/Sampling_Frequency;
t = (0:Sampling_Period:Sampling_Period*(Number_Of_Samples-1));
Signal_2 = Amplitude.*sin(2*pi*50*t);
subplot(3,1,2); plot(t,Signal_2,'Marker','.');
title("Signal 2: 50Hz Sinusoid Samples at " + num2str(Sampling_Frequency) + "Hz (" + num2str(Number_Of_Samples) + " samples)");
xlabel("Time (s)"); ylabel("Amplitude");
xlim([0 0.05]);

Signal_1 = Signal_1(1:2:end);
Cummulative_Signal = Signal_1 + Signal_2;
Samples_Vector = (0:99); Interpolated_Samples_Vector = linspace(0,99,250);
Cummulative_Signal = interp1(Samples_Vector,Cummulative_Signal,Interpolated_Samples_Vector);
End_Time = Sampling_Period*(Number_Of_Samples-1);
t = linspace(0,End_Time,250);
subplot(3,1,3); plot(t,Cummulative_Signal,'Marker','.');
title("Summed with Respect to Time");
xlabel("Time (s)"); ylabel("Amplitude");
xlim([0 0.05]);
```

**Rna using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: I would like to ask what line 2 and 3 does


`%Adding signals with respect to samples%
Cumulative_Signal = Signal_1 + Signal_2;
Samples_Vector = (0:199); Interpolated_Samples_Vector = linspace(0,199,250);
Cumulative_Signal = interp1(Samples_Vector,Cumulative_Signal,Interpolated_Samples_Vector);`

Comment: This line interpolates additional samples in between the 0 to 199 samples. This effectively takes your `Cumulative_Signal` from a 200 point/sample signal to a 250 one. MATLAB does this through approximation/calculation using `interp1()`.

Comment: Say for example if you had to interpolate a triangular signal that had samples `x = [0 1 0 1 0]` we could interpolate this to a signal with more samples that equals `x = [0 0.5 1 0.5 0 0.5 1 0.5 0]`.